# Is there a system-wide spell check setting?

Tags: settings, system, language-support, spell-checking

I just reinstalled Ubuntu on a new hard drive, and now I have to disable spell checking in just about every application. Can I do that for the whole system?

Comment: I want to change the default language, instead of disable it. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/635406/how-to-change-the-default-language-for-spell-check-in-all-text-boxes-system-wide