# How to change the default language for spell check in all text boxes system-wide?

Tags: 12.04, language-support, spell-checking

I have a similar problem to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243065/cant-change-libreoffice-spell-check-language), but my language is already installed. In every text field I begin typing (not only LibreOffice), I need to change it back to my own language, or just disable it at all (it's one click faster, plus I don't have to select all the text). Please, how can I just change the default language?

EDIT: I'm using IBUS in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Are you using your language as the [display language for menus and messages](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-language.html)?

Comment: Yes, I am. Though the contrary would be better, use english for menus and messages (easier to get help online) and portuguese for spell check...

Comment: I asked because that way Portuguese is the current locale, so the Portuguese spell checker should be enabled by default unless you haven't customized the applications otherwise.